# Understanding transactions in Spring Test

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, testing, transactions

I have a little bit trouble with Integration Test and the transactions.

I have a Rest Service System. Behind all I have a JPA-Repository, with a Postgres database. Now to test them I build JunitTest where I made the calls on the System. The test loads the web-context and an other xy-context where I have the configuration of security and database connections. On the test method I have the @Transactional annotation.

The test makes 2 requests (This is only one example I have more of similar scenarios on other Object):

- insert a new user
- on this user create a Group and after bind this to the user

The test makes the first call, and returns me a id where I use to perform the second call.
The second call take the id and make the post and there I have several problems.

Details of the second call:

1. Test make a post on a controller
2. Controller takes the request and forward it to the Service
3. Service method (with @Transactional) take the request and do:

   1. a research to find the inserted user
   2. insert a group object
   3. update the user with the groupId (generated on point 2)

Now one of the problems I had, it was a AccessDeniedException on point 3.1, because I have also ACL, and I have to check if there are enough permissions.

One of the things that I tried to do is to set:

```
     @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

on the Service Method. 
What I get after is the result that the AccessDeniedException was disappeared but the research at 3.1 gives me empty result (the research is ok, because on other scenario I have correct results), but is strange because the first post was ok, and how I understand Spring handles the @Transactions and "commits" to database so that a commit is performed when a transaction is closed. This brings me to an other idea to try: remove the @Transaction annotation on the test, but when i made this, then the database has all the data of this scenario until the end of the tests session (If you have a lot of test this is not desirable), and this is not a very good thing.

Now I wrote a little bit where are my doubts, and problems without posting a lot of code and of privacy problems, but on request I can post little pieces of codes. 
It's also probable that the approach is incorrect.

The questions are:

-how can I make this service work?

-It's the correct way to set (propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)?

-It's the correct way to set @Transactional on the test? (eventually with a Rollback?)

Txs a lot.

To make test I use mockMvc to make the request and some annotation on the class:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { ..... })
@Transactional
public class tests {

  @Test
  public void aTest(){
       mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext)
            .addFilter(new DelegatingFilterProxy("springSecurityFilterChain",    webApplicationContext), "/*")
            .build();
       mockMvc.perform(post(.....))
```

}

}

Comment: what kind of test it is, are you calling the java method or via http? are you using spring-mvc test or plain http?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question:

`It's the correct way to set @Transactional on the test? (eventually with a Rollback?)`

No really, but you can. Because you are doing two requests, the second depends on the first, and http request will not remember your transaction, if you insist to do it, you need `flush` your session between requests.

`It's the correct way to set (propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)?`

It depends. `REQUIRES_NEW` means it will start new transaction, the influence is that everything in the existing transaction will be invisible in the new transaction, because the old one is not commited yet! if this server is the entry point of the transaction, it makes no difference, but be aware of the visibility problem.

`how can I make this service work?`

OK, forget what my answers of the previous questions. If I have to write the test, I will do it this way:

- The test is not transactional. If you are doing integration test, you don't need to rollback single tests. If you wanna rollback the commit, then you are having wrong task case, you should have two test cases `insert user` and `update group`.
- 3 parts of the test

  - Send request to insert user and get the ID (single transaction)
  - Send request to update group(another transaction)
  - Send request to fetch the user and do the checks.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Question: It's there a way to flush the session from the test? Tank's to confirm my suspect that use the propagation is not the best way for my case. You say to make insert user and update group separate. How should i prepare the update Group? Do I setup the data of the user directly on DB? Why I should send a separate request to fetch the user and group? (My questions are to understand you're point of view, I have my own but this don't would say that mine is correct :P)

Comment: @java4fun `entityManager.flush()` or `SessionFactory.getCurrentSession.flush()`

Comment: The problem at the end was totally in an other part of the system. In short terms, I missed to set Business logic to the user and group.  Thank you Jaiwo99 for you're support and you're response. I will try you're suggestion to separate the test (SRP) in the future.

Comment: If I want to remove `@Transactional` from my test, how do I avoid the LazyInitializationException when I check the entity that is read from the service-level transaction?

Comment: In this example http requests are used to get data from your service. They don't return an attached jpa entity, so no problem here. Of course you still will have troubles if you access the entity in your http controller, but that problem is irrelevant, you will have an exception regardless of tests or calling the http request in any way, and if that's your problem you should ask that in a separate question.